# Discoloured Tab Controller after clicking on iAD banner

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uistoryboard, iad

This issue only happens on the iPhone 4/4s(3.5 inch screen) and only on the actual device not on the simulator.

Here is my story board app layout:

[image]

Here is the constraints I defined so auto layout elegantly handles the different screen sizes if the app is running on a 3.5" or 4" screen:

[image]

When running the app on an iPhone 4/4s, this is what the tab controller looks like:

[image]

After I click on the iAd banner, and go back to the view, the tab controller looks like this:
[image]

Again, I don't see this issue if I do this on the simulator (3.5", 4") and it does not happen on the iPhone 5/5s devices.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by defining Opaque Tab Bar in the Storyboard for the bottom bar in the Tab Bar Controller View.

[image]